# Can't modify assembly in x64dbg

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-64, disassembly, x64dbg

When i double click on a line in x64dbg to open 'assemble at' window and change "jne" to "jmp", it takes me to next step and not opening assemble dialog box. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I changed your title to something that sounds more grammatical.  In your "access assemble" phrasing, I guess "assemble" was the name of a dialog box?  I hope the question is still clear, and that the new title describes the overall problem.  Edit if not.

Comment: It works for me. Can you make a [mcve]? Note that if you want to steer the execution flow once in a while, you can just double click on the flags to toggle them. The edits done with x64dbg won't be persisted to disk. You'd need to dump the PE but that's not equivalent to modifying the original binary.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior has been changed to allow a more intuitive navigation for most people. You can still achieve the same by first selecting the instruction and then pressing space (you can customize this hotkey).
I hope that I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on go to "Assemble" if not editable while double click.

[image: context menu]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use latest version of x64Dbg and your problem will be solved to assebly.. Click Help on x64Dbg and click check for updates and you'll be redirected to the right place (latest releae).